# Page not found on new server in Drupal 7 custom module

Tags: routes, hooks

I have a custom module that uses `hook_menu()` to create new routes. It works on all my existing Windows development boxes.
I've recently set up an Ubuntu box, and installed Drupal; everything seems to work aside from the custom routes.  I have a menu callback for "test" that gives me a 404 error. I have confirmed that `hook_menu()` is called in the code. I have clean URLs enabled, and the "Add content" link  goes to "node/add," so it seems that clean URLs/URL rewriting works.

I should add that visiting "?q=node/add" works fine, but "?=test" does not.  It seems like on this machine something weird is happening with the menu system.

Comment: If visiting the modules page doesn't work, posting your callback might help us figuring out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the module requires curl which the server didn't have.  The module didn't bring down the whole site but just didn't work itself.  No way anybody could have diagnosed that!

Answer (score 0):

The menu cache needs to be rebuilt; log in as administrator, and visit the modules page.